# Dividing a 1GB JP2 image into equal small images

Tags: images

I want to divide a 1GB pathology JP2 image into smaller images so I can work with them in MATLAB. As it's a large image I could not read it to memory and I don't know how to divide the image. Is there any way to divide the image in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with MATLAB, and you may have better luck in superuser, mathematics/mathoverflow, or stackoverflow.

However, I note that there is a patch note for MATLAB section R2010b  [[1]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R14SP3&endrelease=R2017a&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=):

> Efficient Display and Navigation of Very Large Images of Arbitrary
>   Format in imtool
>
> The rsetwrite function allows you to create a multiresolution image
>   pyramid (R-Set) from a large image file. In previous releases, the
>   rsetwrite function accepted TIFF or NITF image files. Now, in addition
>   to accepting these image files, rsetwrite accepts ImageAdapter
>   objects. ImageAdapter objects allow you to work with images of
>   arbitrary file format. See *Working with Data in Unsupported Formats*
>   for guidelines on how to create an ImageAdapter object.

Which may be a hint: `rsetwrite` to make an "R-Set" in combination with `ImageAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab [Image Processing toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html) allows you to read, write and convert image files.

Are you going to process the reduced resolution images in Matlab? If so, check the functions to work with [large image files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/large-image-files.html). The **rsetwrite** function allows you to create reduced resolution images from big files (R-Sets), which then you can load with the **imtool** function, [for example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rsetwrite.html).

If you only need to convert between image formats, or definitely the image is so big that you cannot read it in memory, use any image processing software to downsample it. For converting among practically any image format, you could use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/), which lets you work with gigabyte-sized images and allows downsampling as well.